# Can we overcome underrun in alsa using snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_size?

Tags: alsa

As we know that when we open a device for playback, then we have to provide data to device     at the rate device operates (means we must match to the rate of the device), otherwise we will get under-run.

```
    "Under-run/over-run can be overcomed by increasing the buffer size"
```

I can understand how over-run can be overcomed, but how under-run can be eliminated by increasing buffer size. Can we overcome under-run by using **snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_size** or **snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_threshold**?. What is the exact difference between these two?. Any help thanks in advance.

Comment: yes..we can overcome the under-run by using snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_size , i tested it, working. But i didn't understood clearly what is the difference between those two functions

Comment: What do you mean with "overcome"? What should happen when your program has not provided data to play?

Comment: It should play silence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The silence size/threshold settings are more generic than needed in practice.

To reinitialize any just-played part of the buffer with zeros, set the silence threshold to zero, and set the silence size to the boundary value (which you can read with `snd_pcm_sw_params_get_boundary`).

Comment: When exactly the above situation comes into play?. I think that would write silence for full buffer.(here after writing silence if any data we write then it will be played with delay).

Comment: I tried by setting stop threshold to zero(0), then also broken pipe didn't occur. But i didn't know what exactly going on when we set stop threshold to zero(0).

Comment: Writing the silence happens in the interrupt handler just after that part has been played. To ask a question about the stop threshold, do not use comments but the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: i tested the silence trick. It is not working. Then also i am getting Broken pipe errors.

Comment: There are other errors than underruns that might stop a device.

Comment: Fine. I set stop threshold to bval(boundary value) obtained from snd_pcm_sw_params_get_boundary(), then i can avoid broken pipe error but i did not get any sound.(i.e it is playing silence all the time)